# Псевдослучайный массив (с заданными вероятностями)

Tags: алгоритм, javascript, оптимизация

В исходном двумерном массиве хранится **n** элементов. Массив выглядит примерно так:

```
var all = [ ["value", 1], ["value2", 0.9], ["value3", 2.2] ];
```

Нам нужно сгенерировать новый массив, длинна которого = **k**. При условии, что n >= k.

1. Новый массив должен состоять из
       элементов исходного массива (без
       повторений).
2. Длинна нового массива меньше либо равна длине
       исходного.
3. Элементы в новом массиве не
       сохраняют порядок исходного массива
       (перемешаны между собой).

По-хорошему нам нужно просто перемешать исходный массив и отрезать от него **k** элементов. Но это не все условия. Обратим внимание на вторые значения каждого элемента массива: *1, 0.9, 2.2 ...* Это - коэффициенты, которые определяют вероятность попадания этого элемента в новый массив. Это - любое неотрицательное число, включая 0. Если 0 - элемент не должен попасть в новый массив, только если у нас не будет "нехватки" элементов. Допустим, в исходном массиве у нас 100 элементов, а в новом массиве должно быть всего 50 элементов. Получается, что каждый конкретный элемент попадет в новый массив с вероятностью 0.5. Это дефолтная вероятность, которую мы должны учитывать. Более того, скажем, коэффициент этого конкретного элемента = 2.3, а это должно означать, что этот элемент должен попасть в новый массив в 2.3 раза вероятнее, чем, скажем, элемент, у которого этот коэффициент равнялся бы единице.

> Если бы у всех элементов коэффициенты
> равнялись бы единице, они все были бы
> равноправные и одинаково часто
> попадали бы в новый массив.

Соответственно, если коэффициент < 1, то элемент будет попадать в новый массив с меньшей вероятностью. Стоит подчеркнуть, что если рядом стоят 2 элемента, у которых коэффициенты равны соответственно 0.001 и 1000, то оба эти элемента могут попасть в новый массив. У нас нет предвзятости, только случайность.

Я набросал код. Он также может помочь понять требования к алгоритму. Однако сложность моего алгоритма чрезвычайно высока. Алгоритм нерационален. Прошу помочь с идеями по оптимизации.

http://jsfiddle.net/s9gf2z4g/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суммируем вероятности. Генерируем случайное число 0 <= x < sum. Идем по массиву (лучше по списку), пока сумма пройденных элементов меньше сгенерированного случайного значения. Добавляем в результирующий список соответствующий элемент исходного, а из исходного - удаляем. Повторяем цикл, уменьшив сумму, конечно, на вес исключенного элемента.

JavaScript я не знаю, вот код на Пайтоне, он читается почти как этот текст на английском.

```
import random

src = [ ("value", 1), ("value2", 0.9), ("value3", 2.2) ];
dst = []

while (len(dst) < 2):
    r = random.random() * sum(i[1] for i in src)
    s = 0
    x = len(src) - 1
    for i in range(len(src)):
        s += src[i][1]
        if s >= r:
            x = i
            break
    dst.append(src[x][0])
    del src[x]

print(src)
print(dst)
```